# valgrind errors: --track-origins=yes

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, valgrind

When I run valgrind -s on my program it doesn't find any errors, but when I run valgrind -s (...)--track-origins=yes it finds some errors. Is it normal?

I thought --track-origins=yes was just supposed to tell me where I went wrong in my program.

this is the code:

```
    bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // TODO
    FILE *file = NULL;
    file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    char word[LENGTH +1];
    bool load_bool = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        table[i] = malloc (sizeof(node));
        table[i]->next = NULL;
    }
    int arr[N];
    /* for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {arr[i] = 0;} */
    while(fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF)
    {
        unsigned int index = hash(word);
        // arr[index]++;
        words_loaded ++;
        node *new = malloc(sizeof(node));
        new->next = table[index]->next;
        strcpy(new->word, word);
        table[index]->next = new;
        load_bool = true;
    }
    fclose(file);
    if (load_bool == true)
    {return true;} else {return false;}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool unload(void)
{
    // TODO

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        while (table[i] != NULL)
            {node *cursor = table[i]->next;
            free(table[i]);
            table[i] = cursor;}
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please show us the source code and the errors if you can. Is this difference repeatable? And which version of Valgrind are you using (and OS and compiler)?

Comment: I don't know which version of Valgrind I'm using. In the terminal I'm typing "valgrind -s, ./name of program, and --track-origins=yes. (language is C). I'm using visual studio. I'm new here, I hope I answered the questions.

Comment: I presume that you mean vscode. Assuming that you are using Linux, `lsb_release -a` will tell you what your OS is. Valgrind prints its version number. `gcc --version` will tell you the compiler version. If you don't yet know how to start a terminal to run the abpve commands, look for a tutorial.

Comment: I'm using windows 11. I'm using the visual studio code of the Harvard course cs50. (I don't know if there are any differences)

Comment: You aren't running Valgrind on Windows 11. Valgrind does not support Windows. Most likely in this case you are using WSL.

Comment: I found this description on the vscode adaptation I'm using: Environments are based on cs50/codespace, which is based on cs50/cli, which is based on Ubuntu 22.04. 

When I run gcc --version, i see: 
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04.1) 11.3.0